# Rails linking to a nested resource from outside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a (simplified) routing like:

```
resources :users do
    resources :messages
end

resources :searches
```

I have a Search model/resource, following Railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form

Now when my search is complete, I'd like to have a link to the actual message which is under user_message_path, but I don't have access to it under the Search resource since it's not nested within.

Is this a problem with the way I've routed/designed it or is there a Rails way of accessing this, like a helper method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to relate two things which are not related.  You have users which have nested messages, and you have searches.  Just link to the message with user_message_path, it doesn't have to be **under** the Search resource or related to the search resource at all.

The link probably looks like

```
user_message_path([@user, @message])
```

Comment: I should probably mention that my user has messages split into sent_messages and received_messages.  However in my search model, my method is using "Message.find(:all, :conditions => conditions)".  I tried defining two find methods, one for sent and one for received in the Search model and concatenating the two searches, however it didn't work.  That forced me to have a reference to the user in my Search model, which doesn't seem Rails-like either way